# Use XMS Webshere Mq without installing MQ client

Tags: ibm-mq

Hi I want to use XMS library without installing mq client to my local machine,but I got these error.When i check ibm feature set they said we fix it but how?I also tried 8.0.0.7 version but error is same.
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IC89514

```
            var factoryfactory = XMSFactoryFactory.GetInstance(XMSC.CT_WMQ);
            var connectionfactory = factoryfactory.CreateConnectionFactory();

            connectionfactory.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_QUEUE_MANAGER, QueueManagerName);
            connectionfactory.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_HOST_NAME, HostName);
            connectionfactory.SetIntProperty(XMSC.WMQ_PORT, Port);
            connectionfactory.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_CHANNEL, channelName);
            connectionfactory.SetIntProperty(XMSC.WMQ_BROKER_VERSION, XMSC.WMQ_BROKER_V2);
            connectionfactory.SetIntProperty(XMSC.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE, XMSC.WMQ_CM_CLIENT_UNMANAGED);

            Console.WriteLine("Creating connection");
            var connection = connectionfactory.CreateConnection();
```

> ```
> System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'IBM.WMQ.ManagedCommonServices' from assembly 'IBM.XMS.Client.WMQ, Version=8.0.0.6, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=d2666ab12fca862b'.
>    at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetType(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, ObjectHandleOnStack type)
> ```

Comment: With IBM MQ v9.0.5 redistributable client,you should be able to use XMS.NET

Comment: @subbaraoc Thats what the documentation says but I still can't get it to load correctly

Comment: You can try by adding the following in the app.config file
<appSettings>
   <add key="MQCSCLASS" value="amqmdnet(IBM.WMQ.ManagedCommonServices)"/>
  </appSettings>

Comment: @JamesLaPenn did you get it to work?

Comment: @JoshMc I did!  I didn't see subbaraoc 's answer, but hes right, I had to do basically the same thing.  I'll add my own aswer since its a bit long

Answer (score 2):

> You can try by adding the following in the app.config file `<appSettings> <add key="MQCSCLASS" value="amqmdnet(IBM.WMQ.ManagedCommonServices)"/> </appSettings>`– subbaraoc Oct 3 at 16:35

Use amqmdnet.dll (IBM.WMQ.ManagedCommonServices) for common default
use IBM.XMS.Client.WMQ.dll (IBM.XMS.Client.WMQ.XmsManagedCommonServices) for XMS.

This will force the client library to directly load the common service class. This class has to be present in one of the search locations. E.g.: current working directory, GAC, ...

Answer (score 0):

I use XMS.NET so there was a bit more I had to do.
First of all, you have to be on the correct version of the libraries for this to work.

After looking through the decompiled source of the XMS libraries, I found that the initialization calls look at your App.config file for the MQCSCLASS property as others have mentioned.

So adding the appropriate class to that property is necessary, I had to use the following:

You need to have a at least version 9.0.5 of the XMS Redistributable MQ libraries from IBM.
You need to specifically configure client libraries for your setup, the documentation outlines that process.
You'll need to reference the XMS.NET libraries in addition to amqmdnet.dll

Answer (score -1):

No, not possible at the moment. MQ Client must be installed to use XMS because XMS uses underlying MQ .NET assemblies for connectivity to queue manager.

Comment: I download the assemblies from nuget?If only dll needs from xms that time I can find add to my project.Why I need mq client for that purpose

Comment: What have you downloaded from Nuget? XMS assemblies are dependent on MQ .net assemblies and MQ .net assemblies come as part of MQ client.

Comment: I believe this answer is out of date